# Getting an Ethernet interface back without rebooting

Tags: networking, ethernet

If I boot Linux with a Thunderbolt--Ethernet adapter plugged in, it is found and shows up with `ip address`.  But, if I pull the adapter out and plug it back in, the interface is gone.  Can I use it again without rebooting?

Comment: You could check if this applies to your case: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/thunderbolt.html#authorizing-devices-when-security-level-is-user-or-secure

Comment: @A.B, indeed; thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could write an answer to your own question then.

Comment: @A.B, does this have anything to do with the Thunderstrike attack?

Comment: I won't risk saying something wrong, but whatever access the device is given, this prevents it without validation. Be it accessing to memory via DMA (I just don't know if that would be that) or just being used as a preferred network access conduit and look at network packets. I never got a thunderbolt device in hand, so no experience on its capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you only need to reauthorize the device.

```
# echo 1 > /sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/0-1/authorized
```